# how to get only name of specific user from AdminID which has a child of User-ID and which also have different childs that contain name using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In this image i created and store data on database.

demo data base for better understanding

[image: sample data base to understand my query]

First i get admin id from login user and i get user id from controller through which a user is created by admin and that contain random id and store user name on data base.

```
String idss = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void dbs() {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String? numb;
    numb = user?.phoneNumber;
    final dbRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(numb);
    dbRefrence.child(numberss).child(idss).set({
      'name': namess,
      'title': titleController.text.toString(),
      'amount': amoutController.text.toString(),
      'date': DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(dateTime),
      'time': timeOfDay.format(context).toString(),
    }).then((value) {
      TostMessage().tostMessage("Record Added");
    }).onError((FirebaseException error, stackTrace) {
      TostMessage().tostMessage(error.message);
    });
  }
```

But i don't know to fetch only user name from this type of structure.
I know i can fetch data from structure like adminID which has a child userID and hase a user name and other data.
i am fetching data by

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
var dbShowRefrence;
String? num;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  num = user?.phoneNumber;
  dbShowRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(num!).child("name");
}
```

in body

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: dbShowRefrence,
  itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddAll(
                id,
                customerNameController.text.toString(),
                customerNumberController.text.toString(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        title: Text(snapshot.value.toString()),
        leading: const CircleAvatar(
          child: Icon(Icons.person),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
```

Actual data base

[image: this is data base that i creates]

data displayed on my mobile.

[image: complete data is loaded from data base]

I don't know to get only name.

Can anyone help me to fetch only name from data base?

Comment: "I don't know" is really hard to help with. If you're having trouble reading the data, show the code that you wrote that reads the data - instead of code that writes it. Without that it is unlikely we can do better than the documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write), [reading lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), and [ordering/filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: i just edit my question through this get all the data present in data base but not the name

Comment: This looks unexpected: `dbShowRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(num!).child("name");` In the screenshot of the database you shared I don't see any phone number. Are you sure that's the data that this code loads?

Comment: first database screenshot i attach is for reference for batter understanding how my database structure is working. But i add real database screenshot in my question too. Data that is loaded on mobile screen is from database that i am working on.

Comment: There's no path `$phonenumber/name` in the new database sample either, so this won't work against that either: `dbShowRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(num!).child("name")`. The only way to get only the name of a node is if you know the exact, complete path to that node/property.